# If $v^T Nv=0$ implies $v=0$, is it true that $Im N^{-1}A=Im A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $N\in M_{n\times n}$ invertible and $A\in M_{n\times m}$ injective.
If $N$ satisfies the condition $v^{T}Nv=0\  \text{implies}\  v=0$, then can we say $\text{Im}(N^{-1}A)=\text{Im}(A)$?

This is a part of my attempt to solve the following bigger problem:

Suppose $N\in M_{n\times n}$ invertible, $M\in M_{m\times m}$ invertible, and $A\in M_{n\times m}$. $N$ satisfies the condition $v^T Nv=0$ implies $v=0$.  Does it imply $Im (N^{-1}A M)=Im A$?

(I think the answer to the latter problem is true if the answer to the first one is yes, but please correct me if I'm wrong).

Any comment or suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Sorry. In the original post, I forgot the condition A is injective. It's now corrected.

Comment: Is it a matrix over arbitrary field?

Comment: No, the condition $v^TNv=0\implies v=0$ only means that $N+N^T$ is positive or negative definite and does not help you control ${\rm Im}(N^{-1}A)$. For example, take $N={\rm diag}(1,2)$ and $A=[1,1]^T$.